# Is it possible to disable empathy from autostarting on login?

Tags: 11.10, startup, empathy

How to disable Empathy auto startup? I turned it off in properties, but every time i restart Notebook it starts automatically. Maybe there is a deamon thats starts it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look in /etc/xdg/autostart and the file telepathy-indicator.desktop
edit it and change *NoDisplay=true* to *NoDisplay=false*  and it will be shown in startup applications tool
if you want them all shown for you to disable/enable at will run this in terminal

find /etc/xdg/autostart/ -name "*.desktop" -exec sudo sed -i "s/NoDisplay=true/NoDisplay=false/g" '{}' \;

Comment: Is there a way to do that on a per user policy? I don't want that but I like it to be activated for two other users ...

Comment: from terminal `cp /etc/xdg/autostart/*.desktop ~/.config/autostart/`  you may need to create the autostart folder in your home, then do `find ~/.config/autostart/ -name "*.desktop" -exec sed -i "s/NoDisplay=true/NoDisplay=false/g" '{}' \;`

Comment: thx, I#LL try that.